# Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched. after git remote set-url

Tags: git, github

there are two project directories in my workspace directory.
I decided to change the remote of one of them by `git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here`(as I remember I changed the configs to fix next issue)

now in both projects when I `git pull`, I get:
`Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.`

and when I want to `push` i get this message form both projects:
`fatal: git-http-push failed`

`/etc/gitconfig` and `~/.config/git/config` are empty,
`/home/<user>/.gitconfig` settings are:

```
[user]
    email = forsite73@gmail.com
    name = amir meyari
[credential]
    helper = store
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "new-develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/new-develop
[branch "feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch
```

the first project .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://<1st_repo>
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[credential]
    helper = store
```

the second project .git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<2nd_repo>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
    name = amir meyari
    email = themail@mail.com
    password = blabla
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

workspace/1st_repo > `git ls-remote` --> `From https://git.<1st_repo>` (correct)

workspace/2nd_repo > `git ls-remote` --> `From https://git.<2nd_repo>` (correct)

Comment: Is this because the new remote uses `main` not `master`?

Comment: Also GitHub https: urls are pretty much going away, you should switch to ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @matt commented, replace `master` with `main` which was starting in October